# I gave someone my info and got scammed and my accounts are closing

Tags: banking, scams

So I gave someone all my bank information , because they said they would put money in my account and it sounded ver legit and they left my bank account at -$383 . Then I filed a claim at the bank and they denied it saying I have to pay off that -$383. Now my mom wants to file a police report but I lied to her and said someone stole my card and probably hacked into my account. If I file a police report and tell the truth could I still face charges for giving my information out ? And will they even give my money back?

Comment: Yes, you're responsible for paying back what you now own the bank, and no, you're not likely to get any of the money back. As for the questions about dealing with the police, you'd be better off asking a lawyer about that.

Comment: Giving your bank information out is foolish, but not a crime. Lying about it to the police is a crime. Come clean to your mother. What claim did you file at the bank? You told them you got scammed?

Comment: I'm sorry you got screwed here, but lying to the people around you (and especially to the police!) is not going to make anything better.  When you realize you're in a hole, **stop digging.**

Answer (score 3):

The conditions of your account say that anyone you give access to your account acts with your authority. So as far as the bank is concerned, and legally, you are responsible for the money being taken out and for repaying it. The exception would be if you only gave them an account number and they pretended to be someone else to get the money out.

You should tell your parents the truth. Nothing good will come of lying. You should file a police report, but it's probable they can't do anything.

And you should learn from this to never ever do anything like this again.

Comment: I'd be astonished if any bank dealing in dollars requires an accountholder to even believe in God, much less make Her a party to a (very!) mundane contract.

Comment: $@#%&^ autocorrect. Fixed.